# Where to set maxarraysize for java webservices?

Tags: java, web-services

As like in .NET based webservices maxarraysize can be set in web.config file, is it possible to do the same in java??

If yes,then in which file I have to make the change?

Comment: You'll have to explain what maxarraysize means. You're asking java developers, not .net programmers.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with JAX-WS the size of the byte array to pass through web methods is limited by the heap size. So if you are getting `OutOfMemoryErrors` you could try passing something like `-Xmx512m` to your server and client. If your files are too large, you should consider using a `DataHandler` and [streaming attachments](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/Large_Attachments.html).